# Pressure Difference in Hydrostatic Systems

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics

In hydrodynamic systems, a pressure difference will cause a force. Does that apply in hydrostatic systems? If two points inside a (static) fluid have a difference in height of dh, will there be a force due to the pressure difference between the two points?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, there will be a _hydrostatic_ pressure given by $p=p_0+\rho g\ dh$ The force is given by multiplying $p$ by the relevant area.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be a force.  For example, in water, that force at depth is what's holding the water above it up.  That is how you calculate the pressure at a given depth: the weight of water above it.  (All of this is keeping in mind that by force you we are referring to is a force created on a surface of a given area by the water pressure.)

Maybe this is confusing because it seems like if there's a force than something should move, but instead this is just the common case where  there are two forces that balance.  There's the weight of the water pushing down, and the force of the pressure pushing it up, similar to a car sitting on the road: the weight of the car pushing down is exactly balanced by the force on the road pushing it up.